# Release VSTS build artifact only once

Tags: azure-devops

I am building a continuous deployment pipeline in VSTS. Simplified it looks like this:

`Trigger -> Staging -> Approval -> Live`

In this case:

`Trigger` is everyday at 10:00 (business requirement)

`Approval` one of the senior staff needs to review staging and approve the changes for live.

VSTS has a notification system to send an email for approves list, which is great.

The problem however that there might be cases where there was no changes whole day, but the release would still be triggered and email sent. This would be spamming people. Is there a way to configure the flow so that release would not be triggered if the build artifact was already successfully released? Or maybe some other workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional release environment to check current artifact version through PowerShell (e.g. Build.SourceVersion, check [variables in release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch#default-variables)), then fail task if there was already successfully released.

For Staging environment, choose After environment option and select previous environment.

On the other hand, you may do it through Scheduled Build with **Only schedule builds if the source or definition has changed** enabled.

1. Create a new build definition and enable schedule with Only schedule builds if the source or definition has changed option checked
2. Remove schedule from release definition
3. Associate to that build definition artifact
4. Enable Continuous deployment trigger for the artifact

Comment: This might work. I would slightly modify your suggestion to:
1. Some
2. Add additional build task `Tag build` with `release` tag and add condition to tag only scheduled builds
3. Enable CD trigger, but filter it with `release` tag.

Now I will be able to have CI builds which will not release anything as well as scheduled builds which will run only if there are new changes. Now I only need to get my TFS server updated to the version which has this cool feature to `skip scheduled builds if nothing has changed in the repo`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The email notification will be sent for every release no matter the artifacts are updated or not.

And there is no way to send the email notification only for the artifacts are updated from all the scheduled releases.

The workaround is change schedule triggered release to continous deployment if you want the approver only receive emails for artifacts updated.

Comment: I agree that the best way to go is continuous deployment, but in this case it is not possible as there is a small time window when the database can be updated. Your answer gave me an idea that it would be possible to use CD together with `Pre-deployment approval` feature `Defer this deployment to` to postpone the approval to the 10:00, but I don't really like this approach as it would be hard to pile up the changes and it might bring some unexpected behavior. But thanks for idea.